# Side menue for ios 8

Tags: ios, residemenu

I wanna add a side menue to my iOS app. when user press a button in the currrent view, it should move to right side a little bit and a side menue should come from left side. How can I do this? I used 
[ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController) for my app, but it giving me an exception like

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Missing topViewController',          reason: 'Set the topViewController before loading ECSlidingViewController'`

How to solve this problem and is there any other way to do this? Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of other options
https://github.com/aryaxt/iOS-Slide-Menu
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=side+menu
Or you can do your own with the help of this document http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this library, just add your left and right view controller, easy to manage..
 https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController